# errors "in", mistakes "with"

Tags: word-usage

When should I use "in" and when "with" regarding "errors" and "mistakes".

for instance:

> errors in the graph behavior in the asymptote environment

and:

> 10 common mistakes with prepositions

Comment: In the second case, “with” has the sense of “while/when using.”

Answer (score 1):

They are pretty much interchangeable

> The error in your calculation.
>   The error with your calculation.

Would be understood to both mean there is a problem with your calculation.

In your example

> 10 common mistakes with prepositions.

refers to usage of prepositions, whereas

> 10 common mistakes in prepositions

would mean there are mistakes in the prepositions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

"In" implies very much that you are pointing out the thing and then the error(s) within in.

"With" implies coexistence and is more general, and could be replaced with phrases like "existing alongside".

> 10 common mistakes with prepositions.

This really implies something like:

> 10 common mistakes made by people when they are learning to use prepositions.

It does not mean that the idea of prepositions itself contains mistakes (some of which are common).

> Errors in the graph behavior in the asymptote environment.

There are actually errors/mistakes existing within the graph behavior.

You may hear them interchanged, but for example:

> Errors with the graph behavior in the asymptote environment.

This doesn't sound too proper to me, and could probably be seen as meaning either that there are errors within the graph behavior, or errors resulting from the graph behavior (within some greater context), etc.